# Inheritence Cleanup

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have the following interface

```
public interface IDocumentController : IController
{
    bool Handles(string path);
    DocumentView New(string fileName);
    DocumentView Open(string path);
    //...
    string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

I have an abstract base class for all `IDocumentController` types that implements the interface.

```
public abstract class DocumentController : IDocumentController
{
    private IUndoRedoManager undoRedoManager;

    public virtual void UpdateDisplayName(IDocumentView view, bool isDirty)
    {
        if (isDirty)
        {
            if (!view.DisplayName.EndsWith("*"))
                view.DisplayName += "*";
        }
        else
            view.DisplayName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
    }

    public virtual void ActivateView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDocumentView view = (IDocumentView)sender;
        ((Form)view).ShowIcon = true;
        Log.Trace($"DocumentController.ActivateView(): " + 
            "View \"{view.DisplayName}\" activated");
    }

    public virtual void DeactivateView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDocumentView view = (IDocumentView)sender;
        ((Form)view).ShowIcon = false;
        Log.Trace($"DocumentController.DeactivateView(): " +
            "View \"{view.DisplayName}\" deactivated");
    }

    public void FileChangedHandler(string p)
    {
        if (p.CompareNoCase(FilePath))
            HasChangedOnDisk = true;
    }

    public abstract string DefaultExtension { get; }

    public abstract IView View { get; }

    public virtual bool Handles(string path)
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
        {
            if (FileTypes.SelectMany(ft => ft.FileExtensions)
                             .Any(e => e.CompareNoCase(extension)))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public abstract DocumentView New(string fileName);

    public abstract DocumentView Open(string path);

    //...

    public abstract string FilePath { get; set; }

}
```

and a little bit more... This class contains common functionality for all documents. All is working fine, but I now want to introduce a file system watcher which gets hooked up for *all* `IDocumentController` regardless of type whenever a file is opened. Of course `Open` itself cannot be common as different document types required different opening methodology, so I want to "decorate" the overriden `Open` method in each `IDocumentController` class with the logic to setup the watcher. I am proposing I merely add a `virtual` method

```
private FileSystemObserver observer;

public virtual void StartFileSystemObserver()
{
    observer = new FileSystemObserver(Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath), "*.*", false);
    observer.FileChanged += FileChangedHandler;
    observer.FileDeleted += FileChangedHandler;
    observer.Start();
}
```

which will have to be used by all document controllers that wish to observe changes of the opened file . So in a derived concrete class say `SpreadsheetDocument` I will have

```
public override DocumentView Open(string path)
{
    // Open my document...
    UpdateDisplayName((IDocumentView)View, false);    
}
```

But this will mean all documents controllers inheriting from `DocumentController` will have to remember to invoke `StartFileSystemWatcher()` in their `Open` method.

Is there a way (I am sure there is, but it has been a long day) to ensure that `StartFileSystemObserver()` is always invoked after the `Open` method is called for any derived `DocumentController`?

Comment: What varies between different implementations of `IDocumentController`?

Comment: Could your base class implementation of FilePath set do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `IDocumentController.Open()` as such :

```
public DocumentView Open(string path)
{
    var document = OpenImpl(path);

    StartFileSystemObserver();

    return document;
}
protected abstract DocumentView OpenImpl(string path);
```

And have your concrete document controller to implement `OpenImpl()` instead.

---

BTW, `UpdateDisplayName()` can be simplified to this :

```
view.DisplayName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath) + (isDirty ? "*" : "");
```

and, `Handles()`, to this :

```
return FileTypes
    .SelectMany(ft => ft.FileExtensions)
    .Contains(Path.GetExtension(path), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```